# Unable to escape the governor limits (Too Many SOQL Queries: 201)

Tags: apex, batch, governorlimits

My governor limits are getting exceeded because i need to use count() for each individual fieldName and check fieldName != null, and return it's individual value

But there are over 300 fields, how to do it within governor limits?
Is there any alternate approach to query each field name individually ?

```
public class testAccFields {
    public void testAccFields1() {
        String sobjectApiName = 'Account';
        Integer count = 0;
        String runQuery = '';
        String test = '';
        String allFields = '';
        List<String> fieldList = new List<String>();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(SobjectApiName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        Map<String,Integer> recordListbyFieldMap = new Map<String,Integer>();
        for(String fieldName : fieldMap.keyset() )
        {    
            if(fieldName == 'Id' || fieldName == 'bank_account_number__c' || fieldName == 'BillingAddress' || fieldName == 'ShippingAddress' || fieldName== 'description' || fieldName == 'BillingStreet')
            {
                System.debug(fieldName);
            }
            else {
            test += +fieldName+ '!= NULL OR ';
            allFields += +fieldName+ ',';
            fieldList.add(fieldName);
            }
        }
            List<Account> s = database.Query('SELECT ' +allFields+ 'Id ' + ' FROM Account');
            System.debug(s);
            
            for(Account acc : s ) {
                for(String fieldName : fieldList){ 
                    if(acc.get(fieldName) != null) {
                        if(recordListbyFieldMap.containskey(fieldName)) {
                        recordListbyFieldMap.put(fieldName,recordListbyFieldMap.get(fieldName) + 1);
                        }
                         else {
                        recordListbyFieldMap.put(fieldName,1); 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            system.debug('count accounts where Annual Revenue is not null' + recordListbyFieldMap.get('AnnualRevenue'));
       }
  }
```

here fieldName is having all the field name (350+) which Iam using individually inside a loop (i know it's a bad practice)

Answer (score 2):

These types of computations are considered heavy computations. You will run into governor limits if you try to them synchronously in a single apex transaction.

If you have any other ETL tool like Mulesoft, Informatica you should ideally do the computations there and dump back the results to Salesforce asynchronously.

[Salesforce Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/functions/guide) will be a good candidate for these computations once its GA

**Native on Salesforce Platform**

If you want to run this natively on Platform, leverage one of the asynchronous ways to break the context.

You can use Salesforce [Batch apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch.htm) or a [Queuable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm) to split the transactions into at least 4-5 transactions with 40-50 queries each.

Also, the best query for this will be as below

```
Integer s = database.countQuery('SELECT Count(' + fieldName + ') FROM Account');
```

Notice that `COUNT(fieldName)` only returns rows with NON NULL values while COUNT() does need filtering.

If this is something you need instantaneous then explore Apex Triggers than can fire on insert, delete and undelete of records and maintain this information in another custom object. For very first time you may have to manually populate the rows in this object but once trigger is deployed it will take care of it.One thing that might become bottleneck is performance with these 350 fields. A CPU hit may occur unless you invoke a queueable apex from trigger and chain up to atleast 4-5 jobs

Comment: Thank you for a well detailed reply and correcting the query, Iam new to Salesforce development. I was wondering what procedure to follow in splitting them into 4-5 transactions inside Batch class ?

Comment: It could be a simple batch that accepts a number as parameter. All you need then is pass 1 for first 50 query, 2 for next etc with if statements on the parameter.

Comment: I also expanded the answer a bit to consider trigger if this is something that you need instantaneously

Comment: @CcMda Your batchable could be on `string` and `start` would be `return object__c.fields.getMap().KeySet();`.  That would have the batch scope be the field names.  Then you can set the scope size to whatever you want and have your `execute` run through the fields in its scope.

Answer (score 0):

what is the use case you are trying to implement?
if you have to run database.countQuery  on individual fields then Mohith has explained all the best approachs.

But if by any chance  you just need all the records where a particular field is not null then i would suggest run only 1 soql query  and use apex collections to build your logic.

please find a sample code snippet  to store all non null account records based on fieldname.

```
//hold all fieldapiName

List<String>  fieldNameList = new List<String {'id','Name','Billingcity','ShippingCountry'};

//Map to group account records by fieldname  if fieldname is not null

 Map<String,List<Account>> recordListbyFieldMap = new Map<String,List<Account>>();
 String Query = '';

 List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();

//query

query += 'select ' + String.join(fieldNameList,',') +  ' from Account';

accList=database.query(query);


system.debug(accList);

//populate map  with fieldname key and records if field is not null


for(Account acc : accList ) {
    for(String fieldName : fieldNameList){
        if(acc.get(fieldName) != null) {
            if(recordListbyFieldMap.containskey(fieldName)) {
                recordListbyFieldMap.get(fieldName).add(acc);
            }
            
            else
            {
                recordListbyFieldMap.put(fieldName,new List<Account>{acc}); 
            }
            
            }
    }
}


system.debug('All accounts where country is not null' + recordListbyFieldMap.get('ShippingCountry') );
```

//code snippet to store count

```
//hold all fieldapiName

List<String>  fieldNameList = new List<String> {'id','Name','Billingcity','ShippingCountry'};

//Map to group account records by fieldname  if fieldname is not null

 Map<String,Integer> recordListbyFieldMap = new Map<String,Integer>();
 String Query = '';

 List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();

//query

query += 'select ' + String.join(fieldNameList,',') +  ' from Account';

accList=database.query(query);


system.debug(accList);

//populate map  with fieldname key and records if field is not null


for(Account acc : accList ) {
    for(String fieldName : fieldNameList){
        if(acc.get(fieldName) != null) {
            if(recordListbyFieldMap.containskey(fieldName)) {
                recordListbyFieldMap.put(fieldName,recordListbyFieldMap.get(fieldName) + 1);
            }
            
            else
            {
                recordListbyFieldMap.put(fieldName,1); 
            }
            
            }
    }
}

//logic to handle zero non null records for a field

for(String fieldName : fieldNameList){
    if(!recordListbyFieldMap.containskey(fieldName))
        recordListbyFieldMap.put(fieldName,0);
    
}

system.debug('count accounts where country is not null' + recordListbyFieldMap.get('ShippingCountry') );
```

Comment: I need the count , basically how commonly a field is getting used. The count can be used to do a field analysis.

Comment: well,  code can be modifed  to store count also.  please see edited answer.   if you are dealing with very large dataset  you might need to run through batch apex keeping state of count using stateful.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi Gaurav , I worked on your 2nd solution you gave for count but in the debug it is showing me nullnull. Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: sure.  would be happy to help.   can you post your updated code.   and just to confirm the field  for which it is showing null,  what is the record count for non null values.

Comment: I mean i was just confused,
Map<String,Integer> recordListbyFieldMap = new Map<String,Integer>(); 

Don't we have to populate this map with values?? As we are using containskey() in loop ?

Comment: yes  i am incrementing value by 1.                   recordListbyFieldMap.put(fieldName,recordListbyFieldMap.get(fieldName) + 1);

Comment: But yes i can think of a scenario where if for  a given field , if there are zero records with non null value. it will  not be stored  in map.  for this please see edited answer  to handle that   (//logic to handle zero non null records for a field)

Comment: I was wondering in the map declaration on top , where is it getting its key, value pairs, as the map is just empty

Comment: key is fieldname.   if you   check logic   in nested for loop.   i am checking   if key is already  present   for current field,  if yes  i ma incrementing count by 1.   if no   then  i am inserting   key  with fieldname value   and count with 1   in else condiiton.   so key value will be populated dynamically

Comment: I have added my code in main post, please let me know where am i going wrong with this . Iam still getting nullnull

Comment: 2 points.   your account query is not formed correctly.  relplace query line by                List<Account> s = database.Query('SELECT ' + String.join(fieldList,',') + ', Id ' + ' FROM Account');
 and while getting value from map, take care of case sensitivity.  from fieldmap.keyset()   confirm exact fieldname   then use it to get count in debug.

Comment: Finally seeing some results, thanks a lot man. Any idea how can i loop through individual field names and show their respective counts  in debug. I want to show fieldName : count of entire Fields of an object.

Comment: run a for loop on field list and use fieldname   as key  on map and debug key value pair